# The vbUnicode argument in StrConv is not giving me the desired output

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the `StrConv` function to convert the letter H to its decimal value 72 and then from 72 back again to H.

```
Public Sub Testing()
    Dim Text As String, Back As String, Deci() As Byte
    Text = "H"
    Deci = StrConv(Text, vbFromUnicode)
    Debug.Print Deci(0)
    Back = StrConv(Deci(0), vbUnicode)
    Debug.Print Back
End Sub
```

In the above example I am using `StrConv(Text, vbFromUnicode)` to get the decimal value 72 which works great.

However when I then try to go from 72 to H by using `StrConv(Deci(0), vbUnicode)` I do not get H but 72 with a strange character inbetween.

Is it not correct to use the argument `vbUnicode` here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Back = strConv(Deci, vbUnicode)`

Comment: or `Back = Chr(Deci(0))`

Comment: FaneDuru and Scott_Craner Thanks!